# How to skip two different categories in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Hi in the below image is there any way to skip both the categories in the document in my case both have 25 documents but skip condition works for the first one. I want to skip both 5 documents and count should be 20. In my case, it skips the apple and not mango.

[image: mon]

Comment: In the response I don't see any actual documents being returned what are you actually trying to do ? You don't need `skip` to return the result what you're getting as of now..

Answer (score 0):

Yes just make an array of the categories you want to skip and add match condition before group like this

```
db.getCollection('product_list').aggregate([
{
$match:{
"product.name":{
   $nin:['apple,'mango']
    }
},{
$group:{
 "_id":{"source":"$product.name},
"count":{$sum:1}
}
])
```